# Shehecheyanu on eyeglasses

Tags: halacha, tefilla, blessing, tractate-brachot, shehecheyanu

Does one recite the blessing/berakha of Shehecheyanu on getting new eyeglasses or no? As always, sources are always appreciated.

Comment: I once heard that you shouldn't, because eyeglasses are essentially a cure for an illness (poor eyesight), and therefore not exciting. However making a Shehechanu on a fancy new frame would have a different answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Halachipedia](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shehecheyanu#cite_note-22) writes (my bolding of its text)

> If one builds a new house or buys or receives a new vessel or clothing
> **of significance** a Shehecheyanu is required. [19]  If one purchases **insignificant** clothing such as undershirts, sweaters, white-shirts, pajamas, and socks, no Bracha is required. [20]  
> Important clothing such as a suit, tuxedo, expensive hat, or shtriemel
> can deserve a Shehecheyanu if the clothing brings joy to a person.
> Some have the minhag not to make Shehecheyanu on clothing at all. [22]
> It appears that the requirement to make the blessing depends on the
> significance of the item.

Note 22 expands this and brings differing views, amongst them:

> Brachot Shir VeHaShevach 2:4 pg 36 writes that even a rich person who
> buys suits like he buys shirts and isn’t very excited from them should
> make the Bracha of Shehecheyanu because it gives him satisfaction to
> wear clothing that is presentable. However, if to him it’s like buying
> new socks then one should not make a Bracha. On pg 235 he quotes Sh”t
> Divrei Chachamim chap 15 #201 who quotes Rav Moshe Feinstein that one
> makes Shehecheyanu on an expensive suit.  However, Aseh Lecha Rav (vol
> 8 pg 60) writes that one should make a Shehecheyanu on it even if one
> isn’t happy because most people would be happy with it.

I conclude that this is a matter to discuss with your Rav. You will need to tell him how excited you are at getting your new eyeglasses and how often you get new ones.